# Probability sum of cubes divides by $3$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be random variables, $P(\alpha = i) = P(\beta = i) = \frac{1}{N}$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$.

What is the probability that $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = 3 t, t \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend (but only a little) on the congruence class of $N$ modulo $3$. We want $\alpha+\beta$ to be divisible by $3$.

Assume that the random variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are **independent**. Without some assumption about the relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we cannot solve the problem.

Case 0: Let $N$ be divisible by $3$, say $N=3m$.  For any fixed value of $\alpha$, say $v$, we have $\alpha+\beta$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $\beta\equiv -\alpha\pmod{3}$. The probability of this is \frac{1}{3}$.

Case 1: Let $N=3m+1$ for some integer $m$. Then we have $\alpha+\beta$ divisible by $3$ in three possible ways: (i) $\alpha$ is divisible by $3$ abd so is $\beta$. The probability of this is $\frac{m}{3m+1}\cdot\frac{m}{3m+1}$. (ii) $\alpha$ has remainder $1$ and $\beta$ has remainder $2$. The probability is $\frac{m+1}{3m+1}\cdot\frac{m}{3m+1}$. (iii) $\alpha$ has remainder $2$ and $\beta$ has remainder $1$. The probability is 
$\frac{m}{3m+1}\cdot\frac{m+1}{3m+1}$, the same as in (ii). Now add up. We get after some simplification
$\frac{m}{3m+1}$.

Case 2: Suppose $N=3m+2$ for some $m$. Imitate the analysis of Case 1.

**Remark:** We mention (barely) an alternate approach. For any positive integer $n$, let $x_n$ be the number of ordered pairs $(u,v)$ such that $1\le u,v\le n$ and $u+v$ is divisible by $3$. Obtain and solve a *recurrence* for $x_n$.

Comment: Oh wow I really like your alternate approach idea - seems like it would be less messy than the casework approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $a^3 \cong a \mod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

like person above me said use the fact $a^3 = a mod 3$ (i dont know how to write equivalent so i used = instead).

this mean $a^3$  = $a$ mod 3  and $b^3$= $b$ mod 3

then just divide the case

case 1 : if a divisible by 3 then b should divisible by 3

in this case just search how many number that divisible by 3

case 2 : if $a$ = 1 mod 3 then $b$ = 2 mod 3

in this case just search how many number that equal 1 mod 3 and 2 mod 3

and if you got the result dont forget to mulitply it by 2 .

Answer (score 0):

In words, your question could be written like this:

> What is the probability that two integers independently and uniformly chosen at random from the first $N$ positive integers have a sum of cubes that is divisible by $3$?

As @djechlin pointed out, the cube of an integer always has the same remainder as that integer, when divided by $3$. The answer will vary depending on the value of $N$, specifically depending on its remainder when divided by $3$. If $P(N)$ is your desired probability, then we can write it as a piecewise-defined function.

---

There are three ways in which the remainder of the sum can be divisible by three: both numbers can be $0$ (modulo $3$); the first number can be $1$ and the second can be $2$ (modulo $3$); or the first number can be $2$ and the second can be $1$ (modulo $3$).

**Case 1**: If $N \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then the probability of each of the ways of getting a sum with remainder $0$ is $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = 1/9$, so the total probability of the sum being divisible by $3$ in this case is $1/3$.

**Case 2**: If $N \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then there are $(N-1)/3$ numbers divisible by $3$ less than $N$, so the probability of both of the numbers being divisible by $3$ is $$\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N-1}{3}\right)}{N}\right)^2$$

There are $(N+2)/3$ numbers less than or equal to $N$ that leave a remainder of $1$ when divided by $N$, and $(N-1)/3$ numbers less than or equal to $N$ that leave a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$, so the probability that the first number has remainder $1$ and the second has remainder $2$ is

$$\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N+2}{3}\right)}{N}\right)\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N-1}{3}\right)}{N}\right)$$

Likewise, the probability that the first number has remainder $2$ and the second has remainder $1$ is

$$\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N-1}{3}\right)}{N}\right)\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N+2}{3}\right)}{N}\right)$$

Our total for this case is $$\frac{(N-1)^2 + 2(N+2)(N-1)}{9N^2} = \frac{N^2-1}{3N^2}$$

**Case 3**: If $N \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, then there are $(N-2)/3$ numbers divisible by $3$ less than $N$, so the probability of both of the numbers being divisible by $3$ is $$\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N-2}{3}\right)}{N}\right)^2$$

There are $(N+1)/3$ numbers less than or equal to $N$ that leave a remainder of $1$ when divided by $N$, and $(N+1)/3$ numbers less than or equal to $N$ that leave a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$, so the probability that the first number has remainder $1$ and the second has remainder $2$ is

$$\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N+1}{3}\right)}{N}\right)^2$$

Likewise, the probability that the first number has remainder $2$ and the second has remainder $1$ is

$$\left(\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{N+1}{3}\right)}{N}\right)^2$$

Our total for this case is  $$\frac{(N-2)^2 +2(N+1)^2}{9N^2}=\frac{N^2+2}{3N^2}$$

---

We can finally write out $P(N)$.

$$P(N)=\cases{\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\, N\equiv 0\pmod{3} \\\\ \displaystyle\frac{N^2-1}{3N^2}\,\,\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\, N\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\\\ \displaystyle\frac{N^2+2}{3N^2}\,\,\,\,\,\text{if}\,\,\, N\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\}$$